# Parsing json more efficiently?

Tags: java, json

I have a JSON like

```
{
    "status":{
        "server":{"bool":true},
        "request":{"bool":true},
        "third_party":{"bool":true},
        "operation":{"bool":false,"int":-12,"str":"Not authenticated!"}
    },
    "response":{
        "count":3,
        "emails":["email1@mail.com","email2@mail.com","email3@mail.com"]
    }
}
```

**Note:** The JSON code above it's just an example and it may seem illogical.

The problem is I think it is not efficient to parse it using JSONObject and the code becomes a mess.

Therefore, I would like to know whether there is a way to parse it like in PHP when using [json_decode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php).

Which will make me reach the elements like in this way

```
JSONParser jp = new JSONParser(json);
boolean server_status = jp.status.server.bool;
```

I wish you can understand what do I mean and help me as well.

Thank you.

Comment: What about [json-simple](https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/)?

Comment: And what do you want to _do_ with that JSON? Create a pojo out of it? Navigate it?

Comment: Perhaps Java is not the correct language for this.

Comment: What do you mean by "efficiently"? Question implies readability, not performance. Is that you ask for?

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/338586/a-better-java-json-library even though moderator thinks it's not in proper Q&A form.

Answer (score 2):

There are quite a few alternatives out there for parsing/writing JSON in java. Here are some pointers:

1. http://jackson.codehaus.org/
   This is a very complete solution which also has a StAX like API for super high processing speed.
2. https://code.google.com/p/google-gson/
   Also very complete
3. https://code.google.com/p/json-simple/
   If you need something simple that simply decodes everything to maps then you are right here.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to navigate that JSON, the best library for this is, imho, [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-databind). Combined with [a library of mine](https://github.com/fge/jackson-coreutils), which has [JSON Pointer](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6901) support, you can do such things as:

```
final JsonNode node = JsonLoader.fromFile(...); // or .fromReader(), .fromString() etc
final JsonNode emails = JsonPointer.of("response", "emails")
    .get(node);
// etc
```

[`JsonNode`](http://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html) is ultra powerful for navigating JSON.